# Does this series converge or diverge? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2-2}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2-2}}$

I'm having trouble getting this into a form that I can evaluate for convergence or divergence.

Comment: @Dr.MV Really ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle \frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2-2}} > \frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2}} = \frac{1}{3}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Therefore, looking at partial sums, $\displaystyle S_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2 - 2}} > \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)k$.  It is clear $S_k \rightarrow \infty$, so the series diverges.

Comment: When I factors out the $\frac{1}{3}$ I get $\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2}}$

Comment: OK that's what I thought!

Comment: Oops, sorry @the_new_guy.  I thought there was an $n^3$ in the denominator

Comment: So that makes this a convergent series?

Comment: Not at all @the_new_guy.  The series is convergent if the sequence of partial sums $\displaystyle S_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{3} = \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)k$ is convergent, but $S_k \rightarrow \infty$.  More informally, you're going to surpass any real number after a sufficient number of $1/3$'s have been added together, so it can't converge to anything.

Comment: ahhh.  I see now

Comment: That first $>$ is wrong.

Comment: Point taken @zhw.

Answer (score 6):

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt{9n^2-2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{n\sqrt{9-\frac{2}{n^2}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{9-\frac{2}{n^2}}}=\frac{1}{3}\ne0$, so the series diverges.

Comment: This is the better answer, but who knows why people up or down vote

Comment: The above answer was given about an hour before this answer. I believe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should attempt to prove the more general statement that for all polynomials $P(x)$ of degree $\deg(P)$ and $Q(x)$ of degree $\deg(Q)$, and for all positive real numbers $r$ and $s$,

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{P(n)^r}{Q(n)^s}$ converges if and only if $r\deg(P)+1< s\deg(Q)$.